# Made a Backup with TWRP, but the backup was moved to my computer. Can I still flash?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, twrp, stock-rom, nandroid

So I bricked my Galaxy S6 by wiping the system, data, boot, and all that. Before though, I made a nandroid backup and move the files to my MAC in a folder. But when I try putting the nandroid files back into the empty SD card, I won't show up in the "Restore" option! The kinds of files look like these,
[image: These are my data and rom files.]

I just want to restore the rom files. Not the data, how would I do this on a mac? I am currently using JOdin. Could I install md5 through TWRP? Is that even possible?? Please help!

Comment: `/sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS/<serial>/BACKUP_DIR_NAME/all files` -- is this the path where you moved your backup files into SD card?

Comment: /sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS/2016-09-11--21-24-27_LRX22G.S906LUDU1AOG8/(Then the files).                                                         It still doesn't recognize the files. I don't know what I am doing wrong! I will send more screenshots of the issue.

Comment: Inside the BACKUPS folder you need to have a folder with name as the Serial number of your device. Inside that, put your 2016...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience tells me that for TWRP to detect backup files the latter should be in a directory whose name would be shown as the name of the backup and that directory in turn should be under:

```
/sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS/<serial>/
```

Here, replace `<serial>` with the serial number of your device. You can find the serial number of your device using the command:

```
getprop ro.serialno   # prefix adb shell, as appropriate
```

E.g. my backup files for the backup named *13-09-2016.Weekly* are under:

```
/sdcard/TWRP/BACKUPS/X1JE45FGI3/13-09-2016.Weekly/
```

Comment: That was my problem. I simply didn't have THAT folder with serial number. Luckily I was able to obtain it by looking at the "recovery.log". I was able to restore my rom now. I'm so glad that my parents didn't find out I had bricked my device! 