# TWRP restore: backup not seen in different device (same model)

Tags: backup, twrp, restore

I have 2 pieces of the same device (crackling) and I wanted to clone `#1` onto `#2`. Both are running TWRP 3.4.0.

I ran backup (unencrypted) to SD card on `#1`. Backup data is stored on the SD card in `TWRP/BACKUPS/4400d489/2020-09-03--02-42-32_lineage_crackling-userdebug_9_PQ3A190801002/*` (`boot.emmc.win`, `boot.emmc.win.sha2`, `data.ext4.win000`, `data.ext4.win000.sha2`, ...)

When I run TWRP on `#1` again, to test Restore, it says: "Select Package to Restore":

```
2020-09-03-02-42-32_lineageos_crackling-userdebug_9. [...]
```

which, upon selection, offers `System`, `Data (excl. storage)` and `Boot` for restoration, as expected.

TWRP on `#2` (same SD card inserted) says "Select Package to Restore:"

```
4400d489
```

(it is the parent directory... why?) and then offers no partitions to restore.

What is the problem here (SD card is fine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The  number `4400d489` corresponds to the [device serial number](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/157693/131553) of Device 1.
- Since you ruled out problems with SD card, try this. Make a backup of a small partition on the second device on the same card. It will create a folder corresponding to the serial number of device 2. Copy the files from backup of `4400d489` to this folder. I am not sure why in your case this folder was not created but was backed up to
  `TWRP/BACKUP`
- Restore the backup on Device 2 (mount all partitions in TWRP) ,making sure you *don't* back up boot image from Device 1,as that may have device identifier information. Restoring that would create problems.
- It's always a good idea to always have a backup stored on your laptop. SD cards can go bad without warning too.